# How to change theme element color?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to stylize (i.e. change the element color) this element?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "activityBarBadge.background": "#ff0000",
}
```

also  `"activityBarBadge.foreground": "#ff0000",`

I just guessed that it was a `badge` and intellisense did the rest.  You cannot separately color the scm badge from other activity bar badges though.